# Why did the Dursleys give Harry glasses?

Tags: harry-potter, character-motivation

Why does Harry wear glasses before he found out he was a wizard?

Here are the facts:

He lived with the Dursleys, a family of relatives that didn't care about him, to the point that Harry didn't get his own room, own toys, used his cousin's old clothing, was locked in a closet under the stairs and, later, locked inside a room that was used as a storage of discarded stuff.

The Dursleys didn't care about Harry's health (physical and mental) at all. They were forced to raise him. Why did they care about his vision?

This is my theory:

Teachers at Harry's Muggle school noticed he had bad vision, so they insisted that his uncle and aunt take him to a doctor. The Dursleys were the kind of people that are always worried about that other will think about them, so they took Harry to get his vision checked and buy him his glasses to keep up the appearances (they did this "keeping up appearances stuff" in the first book when they bought an ice cream for Harry).

Comment: in the U.S. we got vision checks every year in grade school K-5th. something similar may happen in the U.K. as well. so your theory is probably right.

Comment: @Himarm I didn't know that. In Perú you get your vision checked when someone notices something is wrong or when the institution decides it is time for a medical examination

Comment: Today the UK's healthcare system provides free vision tests, and subsidized glasses purchases, for minors. Not sure if that was the case in the 1980s, though

Comment: @JasonBaker if glasses were subsidized in 1980s, the Dursleys had no reasons for not giving Harry the glases he needed, and also avoided getting into problems with the school.

Comment: Yeah, that was my point. In fact, that's perfectly within character for the Dursleys: when pressed into making a healthcare decision for the child they hate, take the route that costs them nothing

Comment: I can’t speak for the UK, but in 1980s Scandinavia (with a healthcare system quite similar to the NHS), annual health checkups were carried out by the school nurse during regular school days as a matter of routine. These checkups included measuring and weighing, as well as testing both your eyesight and your hearing. If anything that required treatment was discovered, the parents of the student in question would be called in for a mandatory meeting on how to proceed through their own physician.

Comment: They also provided him with food and clothing.  Probably grudgingly, but still.  They're negligent guardians and generally horrible people, but they're not *monsters*.

Comment: Harry had really bad eyesight. Maybe he flipped omelets and pancakes onto the walls. Necessity over monstrosity.

Comment: @Brindha I just had a vision of a plastic-glove-clad Aunt Petunia slow-motion dive-bombing across the room to stop a rogue omelette from hurling itself against a wall, staining it with yellow.

Comment: @JasonBaker Yes, children got free glasses (in a narrow range of ugly designs) in the 1980s.

Comment: Keep in mind, the Dursleys also wanted Harry to do a (large) share of chores around the house. Can't really do that too well if you can't see well.

Comment: I *loved* your theory. You should definitely work on writing HP backstory fanfictions! :p

Comment: @DarrelHoffman good point!

Comment: @Ellesedil I didn't notice that. I thought aunt Petunia was in charge of house chores, and having Harry suffering from neglect more than direct abuse.

Comment: @DRSDavidSoft Thanks! :D

Answer (score 125, accepted):

As someone who was in school during the 1980s in the UK, I'm very pleased to confirm that free eye tests were an annual event. Teachers and parents/guardians were both made aware of potential difficulties and, because of the availability of NHS glasses (free from optometrists before 1985 and free to the bearer of a voucher after 1985) it would have been seen as borderline abusive for the child not to be provided with a pair of glasses if they had been diagnosed with long or short sight.

Harry's glasses seem very similar to the C-range of free glasses provided to children in the late 1970s and early 1980s, and which were undoubtedly the inspiration for the glasses described in the books.

You may wish to note that the company which made these frames also made the [glasses seen in the films](http://www.gettyimages.co.uk/detail/news-photo/an-antique-display-board-of-nhs-spectacles-formerly-made-by-news-photo/176913235) and that JKR was [herself a recipient of NHS glasses](http://www.accio-quote.org/articles/2000/0600-times-treneman.html) in her younger years.

[image]

Comment: Also, Dumbledore's half spectacles are up there. I agree about the "borderline abusive" treatment, your teachers will notice, and raise the issue until you get it settled.

Comment: Petunia somehow _cared_ a little bit about him, **and** the glasses would also be something Dudley could laugh about.

Comment: Interesting. I got my NHS glasses in the mid-1980s and I'm pretty sure all that was available then was the C524/525 style, but in a darker shade of brown (closer to the colour of the 614/615 style at the top right). Or maybe my rather strong prescription limited the frames that were available to me: even today, I'm restricted in my choice of frames.

Comment: @mgarciaisaia Dudley actually broke Harry's glasses!

Comment: I had the free glasses from 1974-1986 and they didn't match either of those pairs highlighted, i had a choice of maybe 8 or 9 colours which i cycled through (I had a new pair every 3 weeks at 1 point)  https://www.college-optometrists.org/the-college/museum/online-exhibitions/virtual-spectacles-gallery/nhs-spectacles.html the flesh coloured acetate frames

Answer (score 10):

I personally believe that it's due to the chores. At some point, they noticed that Harry has problems with doing his chores (cooking, gardening...) that are consistent with very bad vision, and reluctantly gave him glasses (perhaps asked for them from some friends) so that he could do the chores better.

It is also possible that the glasses came with the original Harry package back in 1981; presumably James and Lily could have guessed that their son might have had bad vision (certainly Dumbledore would know enough to guess that). Perhaps, at some point on or before the 1st of November, 1981, glasses in normal two-year-old size (or even a bit larger, if they were intended for future use) were bought for young Harry; with how tiny Harry was by age eleven, the glasses could easily still be just barely fitting (it *is* mentioned that they are by then too small), and once in Hogwarts they could probably be adjusted magically.
Going on from that... *perhaps Mrs. Figg got him the glasses* (at some fairly early point, perhaps around 1983). It would certainly fit both the timing, and her. I'm surprised I didn't think of this idea earlier.

From my own experience... my memory tells me that I wore the same pair of glasses from 4 (or even a bit less) to 7-8 years old, and that a pair bought when I was about 5 was stolen when I was 14 (by which point it was a secondary spare, but still useful, and only secondary because it didn't fit my worsening vision well). Based on that, it would have been very possible that the glasses were bought before school (or even earlier); I suspect my fairly small size at young ages (in particular, my weight at age 11.5 was 27 kg) is a good approximation for young Harry.

Note that Harry had successfully learned to read, and indeed did not seem to have any problems reading while in school (which he would've needed to do much); otherwise he would've had trouble ever getting higher grades than Dudley, since so much of the school system depends on being able to read. This makes it likely that he got glasses before going to school; either by 1981, for chores, or perhaps in preparation to school (though, again, I guess it's possible that he'd already learned to read by 1981 anyway, and it's unclear exactly how much were the Dursleys non-caring for him while he was still a baby).

Comment: "perhaps asked for them from some friends" The Dursleys, obsessed as they are with what other people think of them, don't seem like the kind of people to go asking for hand outs just to avoid buying Harry glasses.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist Sure, but it could've been the same sort of "friends" they tended to leave Harry with when going on vacation or something. (It's discussed in the zoo chapter that they can't find anyone, but there's a decent-sized list they go through before they figure that out.) And really I wrote that section down before I figured out the Mrs. Figg solution (which is way more likely).

Comment: +1 for the chores connection. That was my first thought as well. However, it's likely that Harry received glasses the same way other kids his age in the UK would have received them, which (according to the current accepted answer) seems to be through a government-provided program at no cost to the recipient.

Comment: I didn't consider the fact that Harry could be forced to do house chores. Well, I don't remember reading about it in the books. It is a posibility that the glasses were thanks to Ms. Figgs, but she seems to be a very distracted person.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist the glasses would have been free see valorium's answer

Answer (score 5):

Firstly, I agree with your theory that Harry's teachers might have asked the Dursleys to take him to a quick eye check owing to his constant vision problems in class.

If not that, then I definitely do not see any incident/instance where the Dursleys might have observed or taken notice of his vision problem.

> *"Petunia, I see Harry's behaving oddly; rubbing his eyes a bit too often these days. Maybe we should take him to an eye check or something."* **said 
>   Vernon never.**

In addition, as mentioned in the comments above, I am not completely sure whether regular free checks are a thing at schools in the 1980s in the UK. If yes, then maybe that should be a nice rival theory to yours.